# Ionic refresher get's fired automatically on page load?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

Ionic refresher seems to be refreshing the page without being manually calling the doRefresh. I would like the refresher to only execute when the "pull down" action is done.

Seems like doRefresh is executed on "ionviewdidload" function automatically.

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event);">
  <ion-refresher-content 
       pullingText="Pull to refresh" pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" 
       refreshingSpinner="circles"
       refreshingText="..fetching">
   </ion-refresher-content> 
</ion-refresher>
```

home.ts

```
    doRefresh(refresher) {

    console.log('the current tab that is set = ' + this.tabSelId);



    console.log('testing');
    this.user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
    let self_ = this;
    let devicePos = null;


    let devicelat = null;
    let devicelong = null;

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {


        // self_.loadingData(devicePos);
        devicelat = position.coords.latitude;
        devicelong = position.coords.longitude;

        self_.get_all_posts(devicelat, devicelong, self_.tabSelId);

        refresher.complete();



    }, (err) => {
        console.log('failed to get lat and long :' + err);

            self_.get_all_posts(devicelat, devicelong, self_.tabSelId);



        // self_.filter_posts_by_type(self_.tabSelId);

        // loading.dismiss();
        // refresher.complete();


    });



}
```

on my ionviewdidload function (home.ts):

```
    ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
    let self_ = this;
    let devicePos = null;

        console.log('the current tab that is set = '+this.tabSelId);

    let devicelat = null;
    let devicelong = null;

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        devicelat = position.coords.latitude;
        devicelong = position.coords.longitude;

        console.log('%c executing when position is got successfully ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');


        self_.get_all_posts(devicelat, devicelong, self_.tabSelId);


        console.log('executing when position is got successfully');


    }, (err) => {
        console.log('failed to get lat and long :' + err);

            devicelat = 28.318237;
            devicelong = 111.168137;

            self_.get_all_posts(devicelat, devicelong, self_.tabSelId);



    });
```

is it the default behaviour when using

> "ion-refresher"

I would like the refresher to only fire when "pull down" action is done.
Don't know why the doRefresh() function is being executed when the app is loaded (the first time only)

Comment: show your .ts file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Html use like..

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

In .ts use like...

```
 doRefresh(event) {
    this.userPost();
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: Slots are a feature of web components that are used to make the components more dynamic. It allows additional content/elements to be supplied when using the component that can then be displayed inside of the component.

Comment: In doRefresh(event){ } call your function which are you want to refresh on pulldown..

Comment: thank you , but I am still having the issue, I already have my dorefresh function. The pull down and do refresh part is totally working fine, that's not my issue. the problem is when my app is loaded the first time , it seems like the Dorefresh function is being called automatically..

Comment: use ionViewWillEnter () {  } in place of ionViewDidLoad(){ }

Comment: i do not want to query and load the data everytime the tab is clicked, that's why i am using didload, as it will only load the data on the first launch of the app

Comment: For more details of ion-refresher see the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher